# How to get name of each sheet in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Spreadsheet of Multiple Sheets, I need in cell A1 (or any cell) to display the name of that Sheet (just like with SheetZ then cell A1 `SheetZ` and Sheet123 then cell A1 is `Sheet123` and cells the rest are not deleted). And I will add Trigger OnChange, it will update automatically if I add a new sheet. Thanks everyone for reading!
[For example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qp72f.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkpBH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List of Names:

```
const names = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().map(s => s.getName());
```

Names in A1 of each sheet:

```
function myfunc() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().forEach(s =>{s.getRange('A1').setValue(s.getName());});
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Can you help me with the code when I run the app script it will setvalue to any cell on each sheet. :d

Comment: I just ran it and it worked great.  It puts every sheets name in A1 of that sheet.  So perhaps I misunderstand what you want

Comment: Hi. I have a script that automatically creates sheets and names them.  So the sheet will change all the time, and I really want a piece of code that automatically fills the sheet name in any cell without the puts function.

Comment: What do you mean by any cell?  How do you want to specify the cell?  Do you want the function to have a parameter?

Comment: I have new question, can you help me please.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67123212/how-the-cell-locks-automatically-after-checkbox-is-true-google-apps-script/67123688#67123688